# How to refer to multiple previous rows in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a question regarding data.table in `R`
i have a dataset like this

```
data <- data.table(a=c(1:7,12,32,13),b=c(1,5,6,7,8,3,2,5,1,4))

     a b
 1:  1 1
 2:  2 5
 3:  3 6
 4:  4 7
 5:  5 8
 6:  6 3
 7:  7 2
 8: 12 5
 9: 32 1
 10: 13 4
```

Now i want to generate a third column c, which gonna compare the value of each row of a, to all previous values of b and check if there is any value of b is bigger than a. For e.g, at row 5, a=5, and previous value of b is 1,5,6,7. so 6 and 7 is bigger than 5, therefore value of c should be 1, otherwise it would be 0.
The result should be like this

```
     a b  c
 1:  1 1 NA
 2:  2 5  0
 3:  3 6  1
 4:  4 7  1
 5:  5 8  1
 6:  6 3  1
 7:  7 2  1
 8: 12 5  0
 9: 32 1  0
10: 13 4  0
```

I tried with a for loop but it takes a very long time. I also tried shift but i can not refer to multiple previous rows with shift. Anyone has any recommendation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(a=c(1:7,12,32,13),b=c(1,5,6,7,8,3,2,5,1,4))
data[,c:= a <= shift(cummax(b))]
```

Comment: It's more of a point for OP -- do you really want something that is clearly a logical object to be stored as an integer?? I understand the instinct to want integers, but columns that are logical in nature should be stored as `logical`, if you ask me

Answer (score 2):

This is a base R solution (see the `dplyr` solution below):

```
data$c = NA
data$c[2:nrow(data)] <- sapply(2:nrow(data), function(x) { data$c[x] <- any(data$a[x] < data$b[1:(x-1)]) } )

##      a b  c
##  1:  1 1 NA
##  2:  2 5  0
##  3:  3 6  1
##  4:  4 7  1
##  5:  5 8  1
##  6:  6 3  1
##  7:  7 2  1
##  8: 12 5  0
##  9: 32 1  0
## 10: 13 4  0
```

**EDIT**

Here is a simpler solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
### Given the cumulative max and comparing to 'a', set see to 1/0.
data %>% mutate(c = ifelse(a < lag(cummax(b)), 1, 0))

##     a b  c
## 1   1 1 NA
## 2   2 5  0
## 3   3 6  1
## 4   4 7  1
## 5   5 8  1
## 6   6 3  1
## 7   7 2  1
## 8  12 5  0
## 9  32 1  0
## 10 13 4  0

### Using 'shift' with dplyr
data %>% mutate(c = ifelse(a <= shift(cummax(b)), 1, 0))
```

Comment: maybe you can use this `data %>% mutate(c = as.integer(a < lag(cummax(b))))`

Comment: One thing to note is that your first solution is a base dataframe solution that doesn't take advantage of data.table's efficiency.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Thanks for the suggestion, it will take me a while to come up with a `data.table` solution as I am more familiar with `dplyr`.

Comment: I realize you knew it wasn't a data.table solution.  I only mention that for others that stumble on the question.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor No worries, I got what you were saying, I was going to suggest you put up the `data.table` solution but you beat me to it.

Comment: Just wondering why the down vote ? Let me know what I can improve.

Comment: @Sumedh Yes, that works too and thanks for the suggestion.  I think with the comment from MichaelChirico, the `c` column really should be a logical.